# What is the minimal amount of information required to recover a manifold shape?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, curvature

I was having a discussion with my colleague, and he posited that:

> "If one only has access to the metric tensor, is this enough information to totally determine (or recover) the original (Riemann) manifold shape?"

I want to say no, but I can't think of any counter examples. From what the maths (as I understand it) says:

(i) The metric tensor helps to define local distances and angles as one moves around the manifold, and

(ii) The Riemann curvature tensor can be expressed in terms of the metric tensor

And so from this information, is it not sufficient to only possess the metric tensor in order to fully determine manifold global shape? Or am I missing something key here?

Comment: Locally, a cylinder and the plane have the same metric tensors. What do you mean by shape?

Comment: What does it mean to possess the metric tensor if you don't know the manifold? The metric tensor assigns to each point of the manifold some stuff; if you don't know the manifold what are these points?

Comment: A metric tensor is a function $M\to T^0_2M$. One cannot specify a function without specifying its domain.

Comment: Locally, guys. In a chart.

Comment: @Kajelad I understand that is a formality of definition, but suppose one inspects a given metric tensor matrix , of a sphere. It is: $ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & sin^2(\theta) 
\end{bmatrix}  $. Now I just told you "it is the metric tensor of a sphere". However, given this matrix as a metric tensor, is it possible to infer that this can be interpreted as the metric tensor of a manifold that is a sphere (i.e. I hide the spherical information, or I hide $M$) ? i.e. Can one generate correct $M$, given this matrix, after being told "it is the metric tensor of some kind of "M""?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan see my above response to Kajelad and see if this makes sense as a comment or reply (otherwise I would be copy pasting the same question to you too in the comments). Thanks!

Comment: @tisPrimeTime: what does this expression mean when it's not tied to a specific manifold? Specifically, what does $\theta$ mean? For a sphere it refers to a specific choice of coordinates, namely (I assume) spherical coordinates, so you need to specify some charts containing a function called $\theta$, which is extra information. In any case, that description can't distinguish the sphere from any open subset of it, since you can just restrict.

Comment: @Ted: what does that mean exactly? Do you mean to say that we're given that two Riemannian manifolds $M, N$ have the property that every chart of one manifold is isometric to some chart of the other (and vice versa)? Or that every $m \in M$ is contained in a chart which is isometric to some chart around some other point $n \in N$ (and vice versa)? Or something else?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I believe I am referring to the second statement. From your prior comment am I to understand that finding such an $M$ is not possible uniquely? More so, I am saying we have an atlas of charts, all with same local "metric tensor values" (without telling you the matrix is a metric tensor), is it possible to uniquely reconstruct $M$, just given charts, and the provided matrix, or will there be a family of "shapes" of $M$ all specified to within equivalence relation? Hope this comments makes more sense.

Comment: @tisPrimeTime: okay, so you are only telling me the metric on a bunch of charts and nothing else? Then Ted's first comment applies: you can't distinguish the flat cylinder and the flat plane this way, or the flat plane and the flat torus. More generally you can't distinguish Riemannian manifolds that are covering spaces of each other.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yeah, my interpretation was that there was no global topology here, just local geometry.

Comment: Ted's question "What do you mean by shape?" still seems unanswered. <> There are at least two ways one might make the question precise: 1. If $(M, g)$ and $(M', g')$ are locally isometric Riemannian manifolds, are they isometric? (Answer: no.) 2. If $(M, g)$ and $(M', g')$ are isometric Riemannian submanifolds of a Riemannian manifold $(N, h)$, is there an ambient isometry (of $(N, h)$) carrying $(M, g)$ to $(M', g')$? (Answer: no.) <> If possible, please do clarify the intent.